# Google SignIn using Intent ActivityResult always with RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-authentication, onactivityresult

Google SignIn using Intent gives resultCode always 0 of RESULT_CANCELLED, I don't know whats the problem here.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var googleSignInClient : GoogleSignInClient

    private lateinit var googleSignIn : ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        onResult()

        // Configure Google Sign In
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)


        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSignUp).setOnClickListener {
            val signInIntent : Intent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            googleSignIn.launch(signInIntent)
        }

    }


    private fun onResult() {
        googleSignIn = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            Log.e("onResult", "${it.resultCode}")
        }
    }


}
```

In Log cat resultcode is 0 which is RESULT_CANCELLED

```
2021-05-25 08:02:34.088 26817-26817/com.right.tools E/onResult: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having same issue and after spending a day i figured it out generally `RESULT_CANCELLED` occurs when `client_id` is incorrect make sure you enter `web_client_id` not `android_client_id` in `requestIdToken/setServerClientId`.

If you are implementing in android you need to create both web and android client id from developer console.

Comment: Hey Really thanks for this reply. it helped I was spending whole day in this

Comment: What the actual dang?! For dev I used client id created for that flavour, but for prod I couldn't use client id created for prod - I needed to use client ID from web client? Bro, this worked, thank you very much! But whyyyyy like this, GOOGLE WHY